# Adding a column to all user tables in t-sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, database-design, metadata

I need to add a delete flag column to all 40 user tables in a database. I could write a script to loop through sys.tables, but I thought I'd check and see if anyone has either a better solution, or pre-created sql for this scenario.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There is an undocumented but well known stored procedure sp_msforeachtable:

```
exec sp_msforeachtable 'alter table ? add flag bit not null default 0';
```

Comment: +1 but...seraphym is asking for a way to remove a column. Though your statement could easily be rewritten to drop, the name of the target column would have to be uniform across all the tables.

Comment: psasik, seraphym wants to add a column named 'delete' to each table, not delete a column from each table.

Answer (score 11):

No, it's a manual loop.

Or you could build up a single SQL statement of course...

```
SELECT 
    'ALTER TABLE ' + T.name + ' ADD foo int NULL'
FROM
    sys.tables AS T
WHERE
    T.is_ms_shipped = 0
```

Or the undocumented

```
EXEC sys.sp_MSforeachtable 'ALTER TABLE ? ADD foo int NULL'
```