# Add a column if it doesn't exist to all tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, alter-table

I'm using SQL Server 2005/2008.  I need to add a column to a table if it does not yet exist. This will apply to all tables in a given database.  I hoped I was close, but I'm having issues with this solution.

How can this be done?

Here's what I have:

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable '
    declare @tblname varchar(255);
    SET @tblname =  PARSENAME("?",1);

    if not exists (select column_name from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns 
                   where table_name = @tblname and column_name = ''CreatedOn'') 
    begin
        ALTER TABLE @tblname ADD CreatedOn datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT getdate();
    end
'
```

But I get errors:

> Error 102: Incorrect syntax near '@tblname'.
>       Incorrect syntax near 'CreatedOn'.
>       Incorrect syntax near '@tblname'.
>       Incorrect syntax near 'CreatedOn'.
>       ... and so on, for each table.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779743/adding-a-column-to-all-user-tables-in-t-sql

Comment: @JAiro: That is definitely a relevant link, but the "if not exists" rule is important and makes it a little more complex.

Comment: ok so you could complete the information with this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133031/how-to-check-if-column-exists-in-sql-server-table

Comment: Your root cause of the problem is relying on the INFORMATION_SCHEMA view and having to split the name into schema and object. Just use `object_id(''?'')` and you'll be fine. An even faster check is `if COLUMNPROPERTY(object_id(''?''), ''CreatedOn'', ''ColumnId'') is null`.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You cannot use variables, like @tableName, in DDL. Besides, splinting the name into part and ignoring the schema can only result in bugs. You should just use the ''?'' replacement in the SQL batch parameter and rely on the `MSforeachtable` replacement:

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable '
if not exists (select * from sys.columns 
               where object_id = object_id(''?'')
               and name = ''CreatedOn'') 
begin
    ALTER TABLE ? ADD CreatedOn datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT getdate();
end';
```

Comment: Keep in mind that sp_msforeachtable is an unsupported stored procedure, so it should not be used for production code. Although it adds a few lines of code, if you use a **cursor** defined as a select from sys.schemas and sys.tables, you are using a documented part of T-SQL, you have the option of affecting all or some of the tables by merely changing a WHERE expression, and the performance is the same. Also, you have fewer name qualifiers to deal with if you use the **quotename** function. Lastly, you have more flexibility in using the schema/table names however you wish (i.e. for a log).

Comment: @PhilHelmer This along with an example would've made a great answer.

Answer (score 5):

You'll need to mix in a bit of dynamic SQL. This should work:

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable '
    declare @tblname varchar(255);
    SET @tblname =  PARSENAME("?",1);
    declare @sql nvarchar(1000);

    if not exists (select column_name from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns 
                   where table_name = @tblname and column_name = ''CreatedOn'') 
    begin
        set @sql = N''ALTER TABLE '' +  @tblname + N'' ADD CreatedOn datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT getdate();''
        exec sp_executesql @sql
    end
'
```

Comment: @Remus: Yes, if OP is using schemas, then this becomes an issue. +1 to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
DECLARE @Column VARCHAR(100) = 'Inserted_date'
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(max) = NULL

SELECT @sql += ' ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) + 'ADD' + @Column + 'datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT getdate()' + '; '
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
    AND TABLE_NAME IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT NAME
        FROM SYS.TABLES
        WHERE type = 'U'
            AND Object_id IN (
                SELECT DISTINCT Object_id
                FROM SYS.COLUMNS
                WHERE NAME != @Column
                )
        )
EXEC Sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: consider adding explanations to your answer. Maybe remove the screenshot of code too...

Comment: Hi Jean,Actually I'm just storing the column name in a variable and find out the table name in which that particular column doesn't exist and then save the alter command in another variable @sql which we run for execution for adding.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe like this:

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable '
    declare @tblname varchar(255);
    SET @tblname =  PARSENAME("?",1);

    if not exists (select column_name from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns 
                   where table_name = @tblname and column_name = ''CreatedOn'') 
    begin
        ALTER TABLE [?] ADD CreatedOn datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT getdate();
    end
'
```

?

Or even like this:

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable '
    if not exists (select column_name from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns 
                   where table_name = ''?'' and column_name = ''CreatedOn'') 
    begin
        ALTER TABLE [?] ADD CreatedOn datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT getdate();
    end
'
```

Comment: -1 obviously haven't tested this before posting. `[?]` adds bracket around around an already bracketed name, resulting in `[[schemaname].[tablename]]` which is incorrect.

Comment: @Remus Rusanu: I tested this: `sp_MSforeachtable 'EXEC sp_help ?; EXEC sp_columns ?'`. That gave a syntax error. I then changed it to `sp_MSforeachtable 'EXEC  sp_help [?]; EXEC sp_columns [?]'`, and it worked (SQL Server 2008 R2).

Comment: ...yet you did not test the OP `ALTER TABLE [?]`. Both `sp_help` and `sp_columns` are stored procedures, and the `?` replacement is not going to work because `sp_help [foo].[bar]` is invalid syntax. But `sp_help [[foo]].[bar]]]` is correct syntax and due to how parameters are handled, it actually ends up working. `ALTER TABLE [[foo]].[bar]]]` though does not work. Too keep a long story short: the code you posted does not pass basic syntax checks, and this can be verified by anybody.

Comment: @Remus Rusanu: And I'm not arguing. I posted my test example for two reasons: to provide the cause of my delusion and to possibly have someone explain me why I was deluded (beside the obvious reason of my being ignorant). So, in the end, thanks. :)

Comment: Oh, sry, then I misinterpreted your comments. The fact that `sp_help [?]` works the way it is at least mystifying for me as well.

Comment: I run this exception `Cannot find the object "[dbo].[table1]" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.`

Comment: @Bellash: That's right. The correct solution is shown [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5146229/297408).