# Add one common column in whole database

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I need add one common column in whole database tables.Any shortcuts or query or scripts  to add the one  column in whole database. because near 100 tables are there in that database .Please suggest me any ideas to add columns in all tables

Comment: Maybe you can use a system table to get all existing tables and loop over that somehow.

Comment: you can check this it may help you.
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/160145/add-columns-to-all-tables-in-a-database-if-the-columns-dont-exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate all queries, and then execute them:

```
SELECT concat('ALTER TABLE ',TABLE_NAME,' add column mycolumnname mytype;')
 FROM information_schema.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'yourschema';
```

Comment: Your query executed successfully but not affected any tables

Comment: It's a query wich generate queries you have to execute. So just copy the result of the execution, paste it into your SQL client, and run

Comment: Great answer Bro,Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can use a prepared statement by using the ? operator instead of the table name.

here is the code:

ALTER TABLE ?
  ADD column_name column-definition;

Answer (score 0):

There's a very similar question here:

[Add a column if it doesn't exist to all tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5146070/add-a-column-if-it-doesnt-exist-to-all-tables)

And yes, you can also generate a script from a query as @Kobi suggested.

```
SELECT 
'IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.columns c WHERE c.[name] = ''COLUMN_NAME'' AND c.[object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N''[' + SCHEMA_NAME(t.schema_id) + '].[' + t.[name] + ']'', N''U''))
    ALTER TABLE [' + SCHEMA_NAME(t.schema_id) + '].[' + t.[name] + ']
    ADD COLUMN_NAME INT NULL
'
FROM sys.tables t
```